# Search a value in a sorted array of type int3 in cuda

Tags: search, cuda, parallel-processing, thrust

The **sorted array** is of type `int3`.

```
For example:
{1,2,3},{1,2,4},{1,3,4},{2,3,4}......
```

In a cuda kernel I need to search for an `int3` value and find its index in the sorted array.

One approach might be to use `binary search` to find the value but implementing it for `int3` will require if conditions which might create divergence.

Is there an efficient approach to do this ?

Comment: Do you have minimum and maximum boundaries for the values of each component? Does it have to be an `int3`? How about using 3 `int` arrays?

Comment: @m.s. In my problem these represents the index of the vertices of a triangle. So it might not be a good idea to represent it in a separate arrays.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily done in thrust.
The following code uses [thrust::find](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__searching.html#ga9f1931503e4faffefd2f9d97c974f933) to find the value within the array.
It uses a custom `operator==` which [should avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906774/cuda-why-are-bitwise-operators-sometimes-faster-than-logical-operators) divergence.

```
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/find.h>
#include <vector_types.h>

inline __host__ __device__
bool operator==(const int3& a, const int3& b)
{
    return (a.x == b.x) & (a.y == b.y) & (a.z == b.z);
    // alternatively
    // return (a.x == b.x) && (a.y == b.y) && (a.z == b.z);
}

int main()
{
    thrust::device_vector<int3> input(4);
    input[0] = make_int3(1,2,3);
    input[1] = make_int3(1,2,4);
    input[2] = make_int3(1,3,4);
    input[3] = make_int3(2,3,4);

    thrust::device_vector<int3>::iterator iter;
    iter  = thrust::find(input.begin(), input.end(), make_int3(1,3,4));
    int index = iter-input.begin();
    std::cout << "index = " << index << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
index = 2
```

Comment: I need to find the indexes inside the cuda kernel  we thrust cannot be used inside kernel calls

Comment: I need to find the values (mutiple times but not the same value)  inside the cuda kernel  which then uses these indexes for other task . I think thrust cannot be used inside kernel calls.

Comment: @user3351750: Thrust can (as of version 1.8) be used inside kernels